# Is set_value_at_thread_exit() supported on gcc?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, gcc4.9

This is my first post here so please be lenient :)

I am having a problem with set_value_at_thread_exit() method from promise class (part of c++11). Everything was ok in VS2013 but GCC gives me following error message:

```
error: ‘class std::promise<int>’ has no member named ‘set_value_at_thread_exit’
    args->result.set_value_at_thread_exit(result);
```

I've tried GCC 4.8 and 4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04

The code is:

```
[...]

int result = 0;
Socket socket;
result = CreateUDPSocket(&socket, false, ANY_IP, args->port);
if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    args->result.set_value_at_thread_exit(result);
    return;
}
args->result.set_value(ERROR_SUCCESS);

[...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't supported yet. If you look at the [status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html)

> 30.6.5 | Class template `promise` | Partial | Missing `set_*_at_thread_exit`

Comment: One of the prices of using open source software.  The thing has been in the spec since C++11 and GCC 4.9.2, which has C++14 stuff still doesn't have it.